# How to create overall function which changes styling

Tags: javascript

What I try to do is creating an overal(global) function which changes styling of different elements.

I will give you an example to clear out my question, I have multiple functions which changes elements indivually like this below for exmaple:

```
function changeBgColor(background) {
 exitIntentWrapper.style.background = background.value;
}
```

Which looks in the html like this:

```
onchange="changeStyling(this)"
```

What I tried is this:

```
function changeStyling(input, changeSelector, elementsCssChange) {
  console.log(input.value, changeSelector, elementsCssChange);

  changeSelector.style.elementCssChange= input.value;
}

onchange="changeStyling(this, exitIntentWrapper, backgroundColor)"
```

But how do I pass the elementsCssChange in this html onchange function.

What it logs now is that the following:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: backgroundColor is not defined`

Could someone help me out on this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the dot notation gets all funky with a variable name vs. an expected element.  Could you use an alternative approach? (use JS to set a class? create a BG specific function?)

Comment: `changeStyling(this, exitIntentWrapper, 'backgroundColor')` and `changeSelector.style[elementCssChange]`

Comment: Patrick has the solution.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts set it as answer I will accept and upvote it thanks